# When do we get an "AssertionError: HDF dataset not available. Check your clearsilver installation"

Tags: trac

I am trying to install a dbauth plugin for trac. I know that I probably should be chasing this on other trac and trac-hacks related forums but still I am wondering, why do one get this error? What exactly is happening?

In my case the dbauth plugin is trying to read things like: "trac_permissions" and "trac_users" from a sqlite or mysql database. I have checked the databases, the values are in there but neither of them work.  clearsilver is installed and running as well.

So what is usually causing this error? Is it that the HDF parser is receiving wrong info? Please do not take this as a trac question, just explain me why these types of errors occur.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[a Google Search](http://bit.ly/JnmU8g) should get you started. You should also consider an alternative, because [DbAuth](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DbAuthPlugin) is deprecated.

Comment: Right, DbAuth is deprecated and so old that you are bound to have lots of issue if you are running with Trac 0.11 or later. You should look at the AccountManagerPlugin: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Trac are you running?  Recent versions use Genshi instead of Clearsilver, which means that Clearsilver-based plugins likely won't work correctly (not without modifications, at least).  According to the [Trac wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/ClearSilver), Trac version 0.11 still had the infrastructure to support Clearsilver-based plugins, version 0.12 retained this support in an unsupported form (meaning use at your own risk, you're on your own if something doesn't work), and version 0.13 dropped support for Clearsilver-based plugins entirely.  Unless you're still running an older Trac install that's version 0.10 or 0.11, I'm inclined to say that this problem is due to the phasing out of Clearsilver support.

According to [this trac-hacks ticket](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/3474), you may want to try re-compiling Clearsilver with the Python bindings (this would only be useful if you're running Trac 0.11 or older).